# Unable to install VMware Player 6.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 due to missing modules

Tags: 14.04, vmware, virtualization

I am having troubles installing VMware Player following the Ubuntu official guide I found at this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player

The main problem is that, whenever I try launching a

```
sudo vmplayer
```

command, anything but the Virtual Machine Monitor manages to start, while all the other components don't. Here is what I obtained after launching the single vmplayer command:

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmnet not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmblock not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module vmci not found.
```

I already tried patching the vmnet.tar package following one of the guides suggested on the internet, but didn't succeed.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

to force the recompilation of the modules.

Assuming you have the build-essentials package installed so you can actually compile kernels for the system.

Comment: This is what that command is giving me:

make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Errore 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic"
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Errore 2
make: uscita dalla directory "/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only"
Unable to install vmnet